# using cell address in vba formula

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use cell address in IF formula and I get an ERROR msg.
I defined a AvgCell/StdCell as string, and my IF function doesn't how to read it

Here is the code:

```
Dim AvgCell As String  
ActiveCell.Formula = "=AVERAGE(M" & StartRow & ":M" & myRow - 1 & ")"     
AvgCell = Cells(myRow + 1, 14).Address     
Cells(k, 14).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]>" & AvgCell & " + " & StdCell & ",1,0)"
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be because you're mixing A1 and RC address references.

Try changing to this:

```
AvgCell = Cells(myRow + 1, 14).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
```

and also to whatever line is setting the address for StdCell

Comment: Hi yohai. I'm pleased it's working for you - consider accepting the answer to flag that it is sorted.

Answer (score 1):

I debugged your problem:

Your issue is you are returning an address "$x$y".

SO

Cells(1, 14).FormulaR1C1 =IF(RC[-1]>$N$1 + ,1,0)

does not work CELLS() throws the error replace with RANGE()

I do not believe that Cells() works with that - I ran some basic debuging and found that you can sue Range() instead. Here is crap code as an example. This will not be your final answer (i dont see all your code) but you can use your methodology with

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=AVERAGE(M" & StartRow & ":M" & myRow - 1 & ")"
```

and use the same thinking structure to make RANGE() suitable to your needs.

```
Sub test()
Dim AvgCell As String
AvgCell = ""
ActiveCell.Formula = "=AVERAGE(M" & StartRow & ":M" & myRow - 1 & ")"
AvgCell = Cells(myRow + 1, 14).Address
Debug.Print AvgCell
AvgCell = "=IF(" & " range(AvgCell) & " > " & AvgCell & " + " "
Cells(1, 14) = AvgCell
Debug.Print AvgCell
End Sub
```